# Force transformed elements to affect document flow

Tags: css, animation, transform

I was wondering if there is any way to **force transformed elements to affect document flow**.

Consider an example like this: `[1] http://jsfiddle.net/pmpcanzn/`

[image: scaled element]

How can a scaled element interact with the position of the other elements and not overlaps them?

Element seems to maintain their origin space when a transformation (scale, translate) is being applied to them. Is there any hack to change that?

I'm not seeking for a solution without a transform.

Comment: It is pointless as you mentioned `not seeking for a solution without a transform`, however for those who are interested in, for IE and Chrome/Safari you could fake that by `zoom: 2;` http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/pmpcanzn/1/

Comment: Closing because of quality filter bypassing.

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid it is not possible.

As highlighted by Hashem Qolami, [**W3 transform rendering docs**](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms/#transform-rendering) states:

> Transformations do affect the visual rendering, but have no affect on the CSS layout other than affecting overflow.

Comment: The reason for this it would be to upgrade browser performance http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2014/03/18/css-animations-and-transitions-performance/. In my situation I'm using transition in height to an element to create a slide in effect while I could create that with transform translate and optimize better mobile performance. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: *stacking context* is a completely different thing and it's not the case here. You've misunderstood the statement. Actually a transformed element doesn't act as a `position: fixed` and won't be removed from normal flow; It acts *as a **containing block** for position: fixed elements that it contains*. CSS Transform module [states](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms/#transform-rendering): `Transformations do affect the visual rendering, but have no affect on the CSS layout other than affecting overflow.`

Comment: The statement you have quoted means `fixed`-positioned elements would respect to the transformed parent element rather than the viewport.

Comment: @HashemQolami, you're right... You should post this as the answer, and srkoble, you should mark his answer as the right one. And I will update my answer as it may misslead someone searching for this subject....